# How to create Virtual Host from Apache .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, virtualhost

I am using [Apache Friends XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) in Windows (Local Server). I setup the virtual host in `httpd-vhosts.conf` in an Apache configuration directory like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.example.com
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs\example"
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine when I browse the URL

```
http://test.example.com
```

Is it possible to create virtual host from Apache .htaccess dynamically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The context for `VirtualHost` has to be `server config`. See the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost).

> This means that the directive may be
>   used in the server configuration files
>   (e.g., httpd.conf), but not within any
>    or 
>   containers. It is not allowed in
>   .htaccess files at all.

([Directive Dictionary](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context))

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be impossible. Because your `.htaccess` is used only after your host is resolved by root configuration files of a server like `httpd.conf`, `apache2.conf`.

To put simply, `.htaccess` in the www directory or in its subdirectories will only be processed after root configuration files are processed.

I mean you type http://host.name and apache finds the destination and uses `.htaccess` file on the host to perform some operations if needed.