# .htaccess <VirtualHost not allowed Mac

Tags: macos, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to setup crud app using http://crud-admin-generator.com/ on my Mac
So I followed the steps on the above link to get all the entities generated.
While running the server I needed to setup the .htaccess file on my mac throws the following error when I run localhost on my mac machine.

```
/.htaccess: <VirtualHost not allowed here
```

My configurations are as follows
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/akshat/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/akshat/Sites">
```

/etc/apache2/users/akshat.conf

```
<Directory "/Users/akshat/Sites/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And /Users/akshat/Sites/.htaccess

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /Users/akshat/Sites/admingenerator/web
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   <Directory "/Users/akshat/Sites/admingenerator/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride all
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
           php_admin_flag engine on
           php_admin_flag safe_mode off
           php_admin_value open_basedir none
        </ifModule>
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Virtual Host from Apache .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275620/how-to-create-virtual-host-from-apache-htaccess)

Comment: According to Apache documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) VirtualHost is defined as context "server config", which clearly means it cannot be put in a .htaccess file.